# Short story about a terrible miscalculation on space travel

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, spaceship

I am trying to locate a short sci fi story that I read in the 70s or 80s in Omni magazine. I remember it was a really short story and it was published in the last page of the magazine.

The story is about a group of humans who are traveling to space because the Earth is finished. However, due to a terrible mistake, the computer of the spacecraft has been programmed to reach a star, instead of a planet. No matter how hard the crew try to correct the error, the computer won't let them.

Can anybody tell me what the title of the story was or where I can find it?

Comment: I'm not overly keen on going through all hundred or so issues to find this story. Can you narrow it down with a cover search? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=omni+magazine+covers&safe=active&biw=1236&bih=585&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRmpq095rOAhUjJ8AKHYLYBSgQ_AUIBigB

Comment: Hmm. A quick scan suggests that it was only in the first 1-2 years of Omni's run that they used to publish a short-story on the last page. For almost the entirety of the 1980s, the "last word" was an editorial feature, not a story.

Comment: @user14111 - I'm looking at the March 82 edition of Omni. The "Last Word" article is about how to write a scientific paper and it's not a short story.

Comment: @user14111 - They used to be, but unfortunately the archive has been removed and replaced by the new Omni website. You can get the magazines themselves (scans rather) by visiting your preferred torrent site and looking for 'OMNI Magazine PDF Collection (1978-1995)'. Since they were placed online by the rights holder, I can't imagine there's a problem with just downloading them that way.

Comment: Thank you so much for your info. I will certainly look for the pdf collection, since I visited the Omni site and even this site where you can find a lot of short stories, buy my search was unsuccesful. http://www.williamflew.com/authors.html
I am an English high school teacher and would love to use the short story as an introduction to a unit that speaks about space and the future. Thank you again.

Comment: If you do find it, I hope you'll come back and let us know which story it was. It sounds most entertaining.

Comment: Hyaven't found it yet. I've looked at the contents pages of Omnis 1979-182 without success. I stil have some hope: a friend of mine has a collection of Omni from back then but hasn't found it yet. For sure I'll tell you if I find it! Thank you.

Comment: Complicating matters, it looks like at least some of the "Last Word" articles are written as very short fiction (for example, Sept 1986's "The Wrong Stuff" - I checked it out because they'd started subtitling TLW in the TOC, and that subtitle looked at least potentially promising even though it turned out to be about simulated jetflying- but that doesn't mean it didn't happen before and after without subtitling), so looking at the contents may not be enough.  I'll also do some looking in my spare time.

Comment: I did a quick run through of all the Last Words in the entire collection of Omni (at least, as appeared in a torrent, if any were missing I obviously couldn't see it).  I didn't read them all (the quality often made it difficult) but I did take a quick look until I felt I could dismiss them as probably not the story.  Couldn't find one that fit, I'm afraid, so unless I just plain missed it some part of your recollection is incorrect.  It still might have been elsewhere in Omni, and I'll try to do a more thorough look through at some point.

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like it could be “I Am Large, I Contain Multitudes” by Melisa Michaels. In that story the AI running the ship was given the course to a planet but also told "take them to the stars!". It resolves these apparently conflicting instructions by making a minor course correction and resisting all efforts to change it back.

I can't find reference to this being on the last page of an Omni magazine but it does appear in *[The Best of Omni Science Fiction 04 (1982)](https://archive.org/stream/OMNI197908/Best_of_OMNI_4_1982#page/n1)*.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't accept an answer, but yours is the best so far. I will award the bounty tomorrow and you look to be the one. :)

Comment: Thank you so much. It was on page 60.